# how to loop so that when character reaches certain length it shifts up

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a for loop so that when the character limit reaches 21 it shifts up.

The issues, I am running into are as follows:

- input stops after a certain amount of presses, which is not what I want.
- Every time a line shifts up the next line spaces get wider.

This is what I want the outcome to look like:

Expected result output of screen behaviour with for loop:

```
|---------------|
|111111111111111|
|111111111111111|
|111111111111111|
|111111111111111|
|---------------|
```

```js
/*********************
Setting up varlaibles*
**********************/

let result;
let calculation;
let num1;
let num2;


/*****************************************
Function for numbers to display on-screen*
******************************************/

function buttonPress(numbers) {

  result = document.querySelector('.answer');
  let input = result.innerHTML += numbers
  console.log(input)

  if (input.length >= 21) {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      result.innerHTML += "\n";
      document.querySelector('.answer').style.marginTop = "-1rem";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: auto 15rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.base {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  background-color: #0C1021;
  width: 19.8rem;
  height: 40rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.time {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.icons {
  margin-left: 11.3rem;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
}

.icons img {
  width: 13px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.battery {
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

span {
  display: block;
  width: 6%;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.hl {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.hl2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.calc-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.calc-header h2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 6rem;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -23px;
}

.screen {
  margin-left: 0rem;
  /* changed */
  margin-top: 149px;
}

.calc {
  width: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.answer {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: right;
  /* added */
}

button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row {
  margin-top: -359px;
  position: absolute;
}

.col {
  padding: 1px;
}

.col-op,
.col-op-end,
.col-num {
  width: 75.3px;
  height: 70px;
}

.col-eq-end {
  width: 155px;
  height: 68px;
}

.col-op,
.col-op-end {
  background-color: #093A52;
  color: #01A6CB;
}

.col-num {
  background-color: #0B1A2C;
  color: white;
}

#border-left {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 23px;
}

.col-eq-end {
  background-color: #01A6CB;
  color: white;
}

#border-right {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 23px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <script src="js/main.js" defer></script>
  <script src="js/time.js" defer></script>
  <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="base">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="time"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dummy-nav">
        <span></span>
        <span class="hl"></span>
        <span class="hl2"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="calc-header">
        <h2>Calculator</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="screen">
        <div class="calc"></div>
        <div class="answer"></div>
      </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col">
        <button class="col-op clear" onclick="buttonPress('c')">C</button>
        <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('()')">()</button>
        <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('%')">%</button>
        <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('/')">/</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(1)">1</button>
        <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(2)">2</button>
        <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(3)">3</button>
        <button class="col-op-end" onclick="buttonPress('x')">x</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(4)">4</button>
        <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(5)">5</button>
        <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(6)">6</button>
        <button class="col-op-end" onclick="buttonPress('+')">+</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(7)">7</button>
        <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(8)">8</button>
        <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(9)">9</button>
        <button class="col-op-end" onclick="buttonPress('-')">-</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <button class="col-num" id="border-left" onclick="buttonPress(0)">0</button>
        <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress('.')">.</button>
        <button class="col-eq-end" id="border-right" onclick="buttonPress('=')">=</button>
      </div>

    </div>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `\n` is meaning less in html but will count towards the length of the string you are looping to insert even more \n. The observed 'new line' is only happening because the number string is wrapping at what the browser thinks is a breakl between words. I'd start by retrieving the `innerText` of your display div, breaking it into a line array with `.split(\n)` and joining that array back to a string with `.join('')`. That will give you a clean digit string to parse and break however you want. If you use '\n' as the line break in your strings, you have to return it to the element as `innerText`

Comment: `input = document.querySelector('.answer').innerText.split('\n').join('');` should get you clean text

Comment: Thanks for that @DavePritlove, I am not sure where to add that in the js code though? should that be a new variable and how would that tie into my for loop?

Comment: it would replace the first two lines of your `buttonPress()` function if you append the addition of numbers to it: `input = document.querySelector('.answer').innerText.split('\n').join('')+numbers`

Comment: Thanks for that, so I tried it, but now the text is not displaying in the screen, I think its because of the ```innerText``` replacing ```innerHTML```

Comment: I fixed it ```display = document.querySelector('.answer').innerHTML = input```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244354/discussion-between-aspiringdev-and-dave-pritlove).

Comment: Is this just to keep your display tidy? If so, it would be simpler, and much less resource intensive, to use css to limit the line length. You'd have to use a monospace font and set the display element's width to `20ch` where `ch` is the unit based on the width of '0' in that font (for monospace fonts all chars are the same width so it's a good proxy for the number of characters). You'd set another style rule to break the string when that width is reached using `overflow-wrap: break-word;`. Your current method uses multiple re-renders of the html dom tree and is considered inefficient.

Comment: yes it is to keep the display tidy, I am also curious how my for loop will change, since the input variable has changed?